# How to print values from lists in tabular format (python)?

Tags: python-2.7

Using python 2.7, I want to display the values in tabular format, without using pandas/prettytable. I am a beginner to python and am trying to learn.

Below is the values I have in list

```
listA = ["Alpha","Beta","gama","cat"]
data = [["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"],["I","J","K","L"],["M","N","O","P"]]
```

Expected output - to be displayed like below in tabular format :

```
Alpha  Beta  gama  cat    
A      B     C     D   
E      F     G     H     
I      J     K     L
M      N     O     P
```

I tried the following code, I am not getting the desired result:

```
def print_results_table(data, listA):
    str_l = max(len(t) for t in listA)
    print(" ".join(['{:>{length}s}'.format(t, length = str_l) for t in [" "] + listA]))

    for t, row in zip(listA, data):
        print(" ".join(['{:>{length}s}'.format(str(x), length = str_l) for x in [t] + row]))

print_results_table(data, listA)
```

Comment: You certainly *want* a lot. Have you actually *tried* to do anything? You won't learn a lot if others do the work for you.

Comment: Yes I have tried with the below code,---but its not displaying in the format which i want

Comment: def print_results_table(data, listA):
    str_l = max(len(t) for t in listA)
    print(" ".join(['{:>{length}s}'.format(t, length = str_l) for t in [" "] + listA]))
    for t, row in zip(listA, data):
        print(" ".join(['{:>{length}s}'.format(str(x), length = str_l) for x in [t] + row]))
print_results_table(data, listA)

Comment: Do an edit in the original question and put the code in, nicely formatted

Comment: Yeah I have added

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close!

```
def print_results_table(data, listA):
    str_l = max(len(t) for t in listA)
    str_l += 2 # add two spaces between elements
    # print the titles
    for title in listA:
        print('{:<{length}s}'.format(title, length = str_l), end='')
    print()

    # print the values
    for row in data:
        for val in row:
            print('{:<{length}s}'.format(val, length = str_l), end='')
        print()
```

Output:

```
Alpha  Beta   gama   cat    
A      B      C      D      
E      F      G      H      
I      J      K      L      
M      N      O      P
```