# Printing python: Product Name product TypeA aS RECIEPT PAGE

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello any one can help me to prinnt this type of python OUTPUT SIMPLE PROGRAM

```
Product Name       product Type

Ceiling fan           Fan
```

Code:

```
Product_Name = input()

product_Type = input()

print('Product Details')

print('Product Name:' , Product_Name)

print('product Type:' , product_Type)``
```

I don't need this output

```
Product Details

Product Name: Ceiling fan

product Type: Fan
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55590145/1639625)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as

```py
product_name= input()
product_type= input()
print(' product details ')
print('product_name : product_type ')
print(product_name, '   ' *2,product_type)

Output:
        product details
product_name : product_type
cyling fan             fan
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use python string formating,

```py
products = [
    {"name": "Celing Fan", "type": "Fan"},
    {"name": "Pedestal Fan", "type": "Fan"},
]


# Raw Structures
row = "{:20}{:20}"
line = '-'*41

# print header
print( row.format("Product Name", "Product Type") )

# print horizontal line
print(line)

# print products information
for p in products:
    print( row.format(p['name'], p['type']) )
```

Output:

```
Product Name        Product Type        
-----------------------------------------
Celing Fan          Fan                 
Pedestal Fan        Fan
```

`"{:20}".format(...)` will have minimum length of 20.
Also you can specify string alignments, filing character (default is whitespace), etc.

[Python docs about string.format() mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)
[Article about string formating](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format)

Thanks!